# How to replace this outlet when there’s a potentially broken ground wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

My wall outlet was sinking into the wall so I went to replace it. I expected the normal wiring: black (hot), white (neutral), green/bare (ground) but found that the outlet was wired differently. First off, there was no ground wire and instead there are two sets of wires: black wire and white wire, and orange wire with black stripe and a white wire with a red stripe. See the image for reference.

[image: wires]

I completely forgot to take a picture of the wiring so I don’t have anything to reference, but this looks like a metal box so I believe it should be grounded. But then I noticed a broken copper wire sticking out so this makes me think otherwise.

[image: Broken ground wire?]

Could use some help figuring out how to get this wired back up. I used a multimeter and checked what I thought was neutral (white with red stripe) to the orange wire, and it caused a spark. I did not notice the red stripe initially so I believe these are hot wires. Is there a better way to check the voltage of each wire?

Pic of old outlet and one I want to replace it with.

[image: old and new]

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a ground wire between the white and black.  Can try using that to check voltage.  120 hot to ground, 0 neutral to ground.  Check if the box is grounded the same.  If box not grounded then hot to box should be 0.  If hot to ground wire is 0, then need to check why, ground broken or not connected.

Comment: @crip659 so I checked the voltage from the box to the wires and the orange wire read 120, but the white/red stripe wire was about 60 so it makes me believe this is a switch outlet.

Comment: 120 to the box means you have a good ground.  60 is not so good,but don't know why.  Were there any tabs broken(connecting two screws on outlet) on the old outlet?

Comment: @crip659 took a look at the old outlet and there were no broken tabs.

Comment: That black/white pair appear to be in a cable, but I can't tell if that's a cable clamp or the end of an EMT conduit. Give those wires a push and pull and see if it can move at all into or out of the "conduit".  If a cable clamp, I would expect no play.  If a conduit I'd expect at least 1/4" free play.  If conduit that is good news.